# Adding padding between the "filterable" categories?

Tags: html, css, filter, plugins, padding

I am testing out a portfolio plugin and have added some additional CSS to it.
I was wondering, however, how to add space between the filterable tags. I have tried inspecting the element and adding padding but nothing seems to be working...

Suggestions?

https://journeysendstudios.com/jenniferthomas/

Thank you! (:

Comment: Try adding `margin`, not `padding`.

Comment: Yes, that worked!! Thank you (:

Answer (score 0):

try using margin.
margin: 0 20px !important;